# I am trying to implement a feature in my app. I want to receive a notification in the background/killed state

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to implement a feature in my app. I want to receive a notification in the background/killed state, and it should be like a heads up notification which should not go away until and unless the user acts upon it. Its something like the uber application where in a driver receives the request, it continues to play a notification sound and remains on the screen till the user performs some action for that notification

I want to receive a notification in the background/killed state. Its something like the uber application where in a driver receives the request, it continues to play a notification sound and remains on the screen till the user performs some action for that notification.
I am using flutter and I am able to get background notification but I want it should be like a heads up notification which should not go away until and unless the user acts upon it.

Comment: I believe in native Android parlance what you want is an "ongoing" notification. I know with the native Androidx SDK you can just use `setOngoing(true)` on a notification builder, but I don't know what the notification story is on Flutter. From a brief Google search, it looks like you probably want the `flutter_local_notifications` package: https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-local-notifications-in-flutter/